# Problems with wc_add_notice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my checkout form i add google-captcha in function.php. Then i am verifing that captcha is not empty and not false:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_process($data, $errors) {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if(count($errors->get_error_messages()) == 0) {
        if ( empty( $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || !(google_recaptcha( $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'] )) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter correct captcha.', 'error' ));

        }
    }
}
```

But function wc_add_notice is showing error message only in next page (thankyou.php). Order is sending. But i want thankyou.php is not loading if captcha is false or empty. What should i add to this code?  It must function like in the case with required fields. If there is a fault - error message is appeared and user stays on the same page.

Comment: why would you need to count the error first before checking if recaptcha is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just remove the `if(count($errors->get_error_messages()) == 0)` and it should work. You're getting the error on the thank you page because of that `if` statement.

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_process($data, $errors) {

        if ( empty( $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || !(google_recaptcha( $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'] )) ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Please enter correct captcha.', 'error' ));

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Now this message is showing on the cart page (if other required fields is missing). But captcha is not working as normal captcha. If it is empty but other fields are good, user go to the thank you page. User should be stayed on the cart.php or checkout.php. Do you know what i should add in code for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what action are you using?

Comment: try using `throw new Exception` instead... please check my updated code..